# ClassNotFoundException when running Google Maps API v2 on Genymotion Emulator

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, google-maps-api-2, google-play-services, genymotion

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find 
>   class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" 
>   on path: /data/app/com.example.nagivationalmapktm-1.apk

I've imported the GooglePlayServices and added it to my project, then also I'm getting this error. Please Help

Comment: Right click on your project goto properties. Java Build Path. Choose Order export tab. Make sure that Android Private Libraries is selected. If you have referenced library project. do the same for the library project also. Clean and Build. try this if it helps

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to use google map api v2 for the first time than...follow each and every step of below link carefully.

https://expertsview.wordpress.com/2013/07/05/google-maps-android-api-v2-quick-start-guide/

if you are trying to build on emulator than..
point 3 in above link might be usefull to you

3.Install a compatible version of the Google APIs platform.If you want to test your app on the emulator, expand the directory for Android 4.2.2 (API 17) or a higher version, select Google APIs, and install it. Then create a new AVD with Google APIs as the platform target.Note: Only Android 4.2.2 and higher versions of the Google APIs platform include Google Play services.

Its better to look all the points and setup a working new project.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously don't have the fragment support library in you compile path.  The map fragments needs the v4 compatibility library in the compile path.  The map samples are a bear to get straight I followed these directions.  http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html